# What can negatively impact a motherboard's / CPU's clock generator / oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, clock, cpu, interference

Is it possible for a clock generator / oscillator to be skewed by something from the electrical grid (e.g. to work perfectly fine at place A, and have issues at place B - all reproducible)?

What would be the user perceived symptoms of such an impact within the OS (any OS)?

Is there any way to improve stability of said clock generators?

Edit:
Issues that I observe: stuttering with any kind of inputs (mouse/keyboard), missing inputs, unstable frame time in OS and applications, significant reduction of video and audio quality, blur-like screen effect (like pixels are trembling when something active is happening on the screen).

My guess was that there is RFI on the power grid that is impacting oscillator of the mobo and thus I have those side effects. As if the PC's time plane is significantly different from real time plane - but this effect fully disappears in another location; any device is impacted, not just one.

Comment: to improve stability, provide consistent voltage regardless of current draw and keep the temperature the same (cool).  symptoms depend on what the clock does for the system.

Comment: Also, avoid areas with high RF interference. Near an over-the horizon radar, for example, noise might affect the clock -- though probably not very reproducibly.

Comment: you might want to mention the sorts of issues you are observing...

Comment: Issues that I observe - stuttering with any kind of inputs (mouse/keyboard), missing inputs, unstable frame time in OS and applications, significant reduction of video and audio quality, blur-like screen effect (like pixels are trembling when something active is happening on the screen). my guess was that there is RFI on the power grid that is impacting oscillator of the mobo and thus I have those side effects. like as if PC's time plane is significantly different from real time plane - but this effect fully disappears in another location; any device is impacted, not just one.

Comment: Please can you edit new information into your question, don't post it im comments, otherwise readers have to piece together the full question in their head. Please rephrase the question to contain the new text, **don't** just dump it at the end under an 'Edit' heading. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: Is the ambient temperature the same in both locations?

Comment: yes, it's not specific to temperatures. It can be ~30C, it can be ~15C. but both locations normally are in 22-24 range.

Comment: @user_1818839 no, computers don't operate like this. existence of network adapter (physically or logically) doesn't have any influence. not to mention that symptoms are visible in BIOS, linux, unix, macOS, ios etc

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Yes, but not very likely.

PCs internal power networks are notoriously noisy to begin with, it would take one hell of an interference source to make them worse.

The oscillator modules (or crystals) used are generally the cheapest that will meet spec, and spec is not that tight, they do drift often by several seconds a day, and this is temperature dependent.

You improve timekeeping by locking to an external reference, generally today either via NTP, PTP or 1PPS input from a much better timing reference (I normally use GPS time for this). Given the right gear you can get way below microsecond offsets between any two points on the planet, it is THAT good.

Of course the cpu clock itself can be all over the shop, between frequency scaling, thermal throttling, and all the other shenanigans a modern cpu does. This number varies wildly even if the oscillator itself was perfect.

Comment: it's not so much about the time keeping, but about the reliance of other devices on the oscillator (GPU, ethernet adapter, USB hub) to process "live" events. The effects that I have are not specific to one PC, I have it on 3 different PCs spanning 12 years (C2D released in 2008, 4th and 8th generation of intel, playstation, macbook 2020) - all have the same exact issue, which starts in BIOS and exists in windows, ubuntu, macOS etc.

Comment: That's (probably) not the oscillators, that's probably just EM being picked up in USB and video cables. I had a BAD case of this some years back when CRT monitors were still a thing, turned out that due to a wiring error the live and neutral were taking very different paths around the room, the resulting field beat with the CRT frame rate in a most funky manner. While I would not expect an LCD to suffer the same way, it could happen if it was messing with the pixel clock line to the panel, and USB is notorious for acting flaky in these situations.

Comment: why I think it's oscillators, is because the effect is persistent until I connect the device to another grid. e.g. I take my laptop to location A (bad one), I connect it there for few minutes so issues start to appear, I disconnect it and those effects will be there until I go to location B (good one) and connect it there. as if reference clock is being "initialized" of sorts and then system operates with this reference. 

I don't even need to reboot my laptops for this to happen (to pass bios initialization), connecting the power cable is enough to break / fix it.

Comment: That's not the way oscillators work.

Comment: aren't oscillators "understanding their own time" using mains frequency as a reference? 50/60hz?

Comment: Nope, not in anything remotely modern (Old school alarm clocks sometimes do, but not computers). No computer power supply unit outputs a reference frequency derived from the mains, it is all rather noisy DC as far as the eye can see. The sort of oscillators used in PCs are generally derived from simple quartz crystal references, which at typically 50ppm tolerances are quite close enough for the purpose.

Comment: can conducted RFI from mains impact quartz crystal in any way? especially in a way that would stick in laptop/mobile scenario?

Comment: Nope. Other things would almost certainly fail first.

Comment: any ideas what else can cause this kind of persistent impact within the grid? or what can be impacted within PC?

Answer (score 0):

You could have some appliance or other AC mains-powered device that's generating interference on that one AC power line circuit. House wiring may not be consistent. Even within the same home, one side of the room can be on different circuit than the other side. They get joined only at the breaker box. I would check for problem devices... dimmers, hair dryers, microwave oven, LED lighting,...

Comment: I can physically disable all the circuits at my home on the breaker box, and connect PC directly to the socket on the breaker box - no difference. Can this interference come from the building grid/area grid (same transformer maybe) or beyond?

Comment: Many things don’t add up. Why only the PC is affected? Why not your TV, sound system etc? Then there’s the laptop - many laptops are not earthed, so there would have to be something pretty nasty on the mains. I dare say the cause is probably much more fundanental that what you’re assuming.

Comment: all of what you’ve listed is affected. smartphones, TV as well. nothing is immune.

Comment: Smartphone would be much easier to debug, because it has no cables. What is the problem with the smartphone and does it occur when it is unplugged from the charger?

Comment: problem is with the reactivity of the inputs / event processing on the device - fluidity of user experience. it does occur after device has been connected briefly to the grid, and effect persists afterwards while it's being battery powered, and until you expose it physically to a good grid. exactly the same behavior for laptops and smartphones.
(updated the question with more details). connecting to the bad / good grid acts as a trigger to break/fix it.

Comment: OK, try divide and conquer: laptop or phone, wifi off, data service off, play a movie stored on the device (not stored on network), put it on table without touching it (no inputs), and determine if problem happens with all these potential causes removed.

Comment: network connectivity has no influence on it. you can disable the network devices through drivers or settings, it will not have any impact - video/audio will still be bleak. changing ISPs, router, network cards, using VPN etc has no influence on it